# Understanding this pandas series slice a[::-1]

Tags: python, pandas

Please help me understand how this particular slicing reverses the order of the series. I constantly have trouble understanding slicing using the []. Is there a page that explains it. I think I understand how slicing works with iloc and loc on pandas dataframes. Here is a working exampe

```
a=pd.Series(range(0,10))
a[::-1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just what it's defined to do!

The syntax `ls[x:y:z]` means "make a copy of `ls`, from index `x` up to index `z`, taking every `z`th element"

This makes obvious sense when z is positive:

```
[1,2,3,4,5][::2] -> [1,3,5]
```

(note that defaults for `x` and `y` are `0` and `len(ls)`)

But negative z is defined to do exactly that:

```
[1,2,3,4,5][::-2] -> [5,3,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

a slice works just like a `range()`, the last argument of a slice is the `step` value so it tells it to step by a particular number if it is specified. If the other arguments are not specified they return to their defaults

an Example is this:

```
>>> [1, 2][::]
[1, 2]
```

which means the whole list, so the last argument just tells python to start from the end of the list and step by a negative of 1  (index positions not numbers)

if they're specified it starts from the end of the slice and steps backwards from there

Answer (score 1):

The notation of slicing starts with an index and ends with an index.
`[::-1]` works by first looking to the left of the second `:` and what the first `:` says is take everything. The `-1` then says go backwards so if you imagine you got a line of numbers `1,2,3,4,5,6`, the 1 is where you start and you go all the way to the end 6 at that point we just covered the first `:` now the next part is the `-1` it says make your new list by going backwards so `6,5,4,3,2,1` is generated. Hope this is clear.